# How much clothing should I wear to keep warm in Hong Kong?

Tags: clothing, hong-kong, weather-and-climate

I have checked the weather in Hong Kong for November to December, it appears to be around the range of 16-20 degrees. I haven't been to cold weather countries, and I live in a relatively hot country.

How thick of a sweater do I need? How much clothing should I always be wearing to keep myself warm when in outdoors during this period?

Comment: I don't think you can call HK a cold country, it is a hot humid country.

Comment: Not in the winter!

Comment: From this description I would wear a T-shirt all the time, except when it's raining of course.

Comment: Those 16-20 degree figures are typical *lows* for Hong Kong. In other words that's a typical temperature around maybe 3am. Typical temperature during the day is going to be over 20 degrees.

Comment: @HaLaBi At the same time, I did feel cold in HK but not outside…

Comment: Does HK really hit its lowest temperature around 3am? In my experience most places seem to hit their coldest about 7am, though probably depending on the time of sunrise too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest a thin jacket to protect you from cold wind and a thin sweater that you can put over whatever you are wearing. Both together should protect you enough. The temperature might drop end of December/January some more so the later you come the colder it gets, sometimes down to 8 degrees. Right now it's 25 for example.

What I have to tell you however is that you will never get a good answer to that. I know people from South India who wear woolen hats and winter jackets when it's below 30 degrees. And I see enough people in Hong Kong that wear shorts & t-shirts when it's 10 degrees in Hong Kong. So you will have to make your own decisions.

It also highly matters where you are going, what you do and where you stay. Feeling cold is not a matter of being outside in Hong Kong. Homes and offices are usually colder than hotels and restaurants. Homes have often very thin windows and few have heaters and offices have maybe good insulated windows but a central aircon that cannot heat and will blow cool air the whole day. That makes them colder than outside in cases. I know enough people who walk around in thick jackets in the office and sometimes at home during the days where it's below 15 degrees.

Outdoors it also depends what you are doing... hiking, walking around, sitting somewhere...

Comment: I want to emphasise the 2nd last paragraph; restaurants in particular often have crazy cold air conditioning. The general rule is that people would rather be cold than hot. This is also often why you see people wearing thick jackets outside even when the temperature doesn't require it. Finally, if you want to fit right in, get a puffy and/or a North Face jacket :)

Comment: @Sam I feel this has improved a LOT over the last 3-5 years. The worst time still is in larger places if you come early. They will heat up with the people coming, but until then, it's freezing. Still, the overall worst place in HKG are the cinemas.